# How can I change trigger event of select tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I want after press enter on keyboard, when we are on select tag, it goes to next html element.

How can I do that? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```js
$('.place').on("change keyup", function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    // code
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='place'>
  <option value='aut'>Austria</option>
  <option value='ita'>Italy</option>
  <option value='crs'>Croatia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$(this).next().focus()` - assuming that the `select` is a sibling of the target element, otherwise you'll need to do some traversal. Seeing the full HTML would be more useful

Comment: @Nima I think you wrong, when you click on dropdown menu it open, not on press enter key, right? in my answer, it act like this

Comment: @pedram thank you Pedram, i solved that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do with `next().focus()`

**Working**

```js
$('.place').on("change keyup keydown", function(e) {
  var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
      console.log(keycode)
      $(this).next().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='place'>
  <option value='aut'>Austria</option>
  <option value='ita'>Italy</option>
  <option value='crs'>Croatia</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="input" />
```